# Wordpress theme css file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

According the Wordpress' doc, when we create theme, we need to create style.css file in the same place with other files like header.php, footer.php, however, to make a better organization of files, I put all css files in a sub folder.

Then there comes the problem, when I go to the admin area, Appearance -> Editor, I can not see the sub folder so can not edit those css file in the sub folder.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `style.css` on your theme folder and have it's content:

```
/*
Theme Name: Your theme name
Theme URI: http://example.com/
Description: Your theme description
Author URI: http://example.com/
*/

@import('themesubfolder/yourfile.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem in WordPress (still existing at version 3.3.1 as far as I can tell) where CSS files in a sub directory of a child theme are *not* recognized.  For me, the problem isn't only with not seeing such files in the "editor."  CSS files that are in subdirectories simply *do not work.*

Yes, you can use @import in your main CSS file to include another CSS file that's in the child theme's directory, but it must be at the *same level* as the main CSS file.  After several hours of frustrating experimentation, my conclusion is:  CSS files that are in a sub folder of a child theme are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing, delete old CSS file and replace it with new CSS file, if you have two-three CSS then d'nt worry about that, place other CSS file with Header.php, footer.php, index.php...

Call that CSS file with "/FILE NAME"